# Javascript replace/append statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for help with the following.  I need to add a block at the end of a line if it does not already exist.  The line could be in any of the following formats (M could be either 3 or 4, S could be and number):

```
M4S10000

S10000M4

M4 S10000

S10000 M4
```

I want to add the string "G4 P1" to the end of the line as long as it doesn't already exist

- `M4S10000` - Append to become `M4S10000 G4 P1`
- `M4S10000 G4 P1` - Ignore the line and move on

Original line left out a few conditions:

```
gcode = gcode.replace(/(S[0-9]* M[3-4])|(M[3-4] S[0-9]*)/g, '$& G4 P1');
```

I'm looking to expand it to cover with or without a space between S and M blocks

```
gcode = gcode.replace(/(S[0-9]* M[3-4])|(M[3-4] S[0-9]*)|(M[3-4]S[0-9]*|S[0-9]*M[3-4])/g, '$& G4 P1');
```

Next I would like to do is make sure we don't add "G4 P1" if it's already there

Comment: Would just checking if the line contains `"M4"` be enough?

Comment: How could there be a line `"M4S10000 G4 P1"` if the line were guaranteed to have the format `"M4S10000"`? Could there, for example, be a line `"M4S10000 X"` that should be changed to `"M4S10000 XG4 P1"`?

Comment: The X in the line should not exist.  It is an invalid command for this position of grbl gcode.  If the post processor put anything other than M, S or G on that line, it would not process.  


A little clarification

M 3 = Spindle turns Clockwise

M 4 = Spindle turns Counter Clockwise

S xxx = Spindle RPM

G4 P x = Pause for <x> seconds to allow spindle to get up to speed


X is an invalid grbl command and would cause the file to fail to process so we don't need to worry about it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the end-of-line assertion, `$` (combined with `m` flag). Also the optional space can be matched with  `?`:

```
gcode = gcode.replace(/^(S\d* ?M[3-4]|M[3-4] ?S\d*) *$/gm, '$& G4 P1');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Length quantifiers** <sup>*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Quantifier#description)*</sup>

1. **`?`** - zero or one
2. **`*`** - zero or more
3. **`+`** - one or more

**Line boundary assertions using the `m` flag** <sup>*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Input_boundary_assertion))*</sup>

1. **`^`** - beginning of input or line
2. **`$`** - end of input or line

**String Replacer Functions** <sup>*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement)*</sup>

*A replacer function for this answer is provided in the code snippet below.*

The arguments provided to replacer functions vary and getting them wrong is catastrophic. If you are not familiar with them, open the link and keep it handy.

**Capturing the beginning and optional end of line code lines**

```
    const codeRE  =  /^(M[34] ?S\d+|S\d+ ?M[34])(.*)$/gm;
```

this is a modified version of the RE in the post, where (for readership)

- `[34]` is simple character set instead of a range,
- `?` is an optional space,
- `\d+` is one more digits,
- `M` coming before or after `S` is covered using the OR symbol `|`,
- remaining line characters are captured in the second capture group.
- The multiline flag `m` is used in conjunction with the `g` flag.

**Working Example**

```js
const code =
`M4 S4 G6 P9
S10000M4
M4 S10000
S10000 M4
M4S199 G4 P1
M6S42`;

const codeRE  =  /^(M[34] ?S\d+|S\d+ ?M[34])(.*)$/gm;

const replacer = (match, p1, p2, offset, line)  => {
  const suffix = ' G4 P1' ;
  if(p2 == suffix) return match;
  if(!p2) return p1+suffix;
  console.warn( "Code line suffix '%s' in \"%s\" was replaced", p2, match);
  return p1 + suffix;
}
console.log("code:\n%s", code);
console.log("replacedCode:\n%s", code.replace( codeRE, replacer));
```

*NOTE:*

- The replacer function doesn't validate the input codes. If an unmatched `Mxxx Sxxx` character sequence occurs in the file, the RE is **not** matched and the string replacer function is never called. Because of this the last line in the test code, `M6S42`, is passed through to output without modification.
- The replacer unconditioally replaces an unexpected suffix value on a matched sequence with ' G4 P1'. This may differ from design critera or simply not apply - modify or remove replacer code as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any capture group in the pattern, and note that `[3-4]` is a range from 3 to 4 which is the same as just `[34]`

What you might do it prepend and append word boundaries using `\b`, and then use a negative lookahead assertion `(?!` to make sure that the match is not followed by  `G4 P1`

```
\b(?:S\d* ?M[34]|M[34] ?S\d*)\b(?! G4 P1\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A wordboundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `S\d* ?M[34]` Match `S` optional digits, optional space, `M` and either `3` or `4`
  - `|` Or
  - `M[34] ?S\d*` Match `M`, `3` or `4`, optional space, `S` and optional digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?! G4 P1\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not  `G4 P1` directly to the right of the current position

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BNsybj/1).

```js
const gcode = `M4S10000
S10000M4
M4 S10000
S10000 M4`;

console.log(
  gcode.replace(/\b(?:S\d* ?M[34]|M[34] ?S\d*)\b(?! G4 P1\b)/g, '$& G4 P1')
);
```